# Reading a byte at certain position of a file in C++

Tags: c++, file, byte

Is it possible to open a file and reading an only byte at a certain position without having to load all the file into an array?

For example, having a file of 10 bytes, and reading the 5th.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, `fseek` and `fgetc` will do exactly this.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fseek/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgetc/

Comment: You can also use `istream::seekg()` and `istream::get()`.

Comment: Yup, just depends on whether you start with a `FILE` or `istream`. Both do the same basic operation.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, use [istream::seekg](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) to seek to the position you want to read from, and then [istream::get](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) to read a byte (or [istream::read](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) to read more than one byte).